# jscodeshift is always skipping my js files

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to upgrade my react application to the latest version of Material-UI.  The material UI project include a migration helper script using jscodeshift.  (https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/packages/material-ui-codemod)

However, all my files are being skipped by jscodeshift and I can't figure out why.  I try various arguments and flags and no matter what all files are being skipped.

For example here is the command I use:

```
jscodeshift -t import-path.js Foo.js -v 2
Processing 1 files...
Spawning 1 workers...
Sending 1 files to free worker...
 SKIP Foo.js
All done.
Results:
0 errors
0 unmodified
1 skipped
0 ok
Time elapsed: 0.696seconds
```

The content of Foo.js is a very basic react component.  I was trying to eliminate as many variables as possible.  I created the most basic component.

```
import React from 'react';

import Button from 'material-ui/Button'

const Foo = (props) =>
    <Button>Hello</Button>;

export default Foo;
```

However, the file is always skipped.  I even tried on verbose logging and still didn't get any reason for the file from being skipped.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here.

## First

There is a manual step you must take to make the codemod work, as detailed in the readme for import-path:

> Notice: if you are migrating from pre-v1.0, and your imports use material-ui, you will need to manually find and replace all references to material-ui in your code to @material-ui/core. E.g.:

```
-import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';
+import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
```

## Second

It appears that the codemod for material-ui does not include fixes for `Button`. I tried your example with `StepButton` and it works perfectly.

```js
import React from 'react';

import StepButton from '@material-ui/StepButton';

const Foo = (props) =>
    <StepButton>Hello</StepButton>;

export default Foo;
```

Note that the list can be found [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui-codemod/src/v1.0.0/import-path.js#L1).